# How can I determine to use server code or client code

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-server

I understand that anything that does *not* pertain to the UI should be always done on the server side.

In this situation, There is a Server object passed as a client Object, the methods that I am wondering about are perfectly fine to be manipulated by anyone.

In cases like this, should I always be using client-side methods on the object to take some of the load off the server and keep the server code short? Or should I be re-obtaining the object from the server and use server-side methods on the object whenever possible to make sure that the returned results are always the same? What is the rails way?

I am not concerned about which way will take longer to do, but which way is best?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? That really depends and differs from case to case.

Comment: I am not looking for a specific case, I am just wondering, if I truly have the option to use client or server side methods on the same object without any harm, which should I be using?

Comment: Guess my answer is then. Whatever you prefer and makes sense for your project. Maybe this question is better for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @akuhn when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take validation as an example. A normal system **should** have (at least) 3 level of validation:

- Client
- Server
- Database

All three levels have to produce the same result for a piece of data. 
Client validation just helps improving UX, not substitutes for Server and Database validation.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning validation, I've never heard about this term before

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "All three levels have to produce the same result for a piece of data", so by that you mean, if I have a method on the server side that does something, I must have something on the client side that does the same thing?

Comment: Well, you must have done email validation for a thousand times. On client you have Javascript regex to validate the email string. This improves UX, users can quickly fix there input mistake. When validation passed, you post the data to server. On server, when you receive the email string, you have server code to validate that email again, because you should never trust what we get from client. When server validation passed, you put the data to database. There you might have some constraints or triggers, or store procedures to validate the email string again.